# Definition of \par modified after "center" environment

Tags: paragraphs, typography, center

I have redefined the command `\par` as indicated in [this TUGboat article](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-2/tb89glister.pdf) (page 232).
But when I use the `center` environment the structure of the paragraphs is modified in a strange way (like if `\parfillskip = 0pt`).
I have no idea why and how the `center` environment affects the definition of `\par`, do you have any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldpar\par

\def\newpar{%
\ifhmode\unskip%
    \strut\vadjust{}\nobreak%
    \discretionary{}%
        {\hbox{\hskip2\parindent%
            \vrule depth 273sp%
            width 0sp height \ht\strutbox}}%
        {\hbox{\hskip\parindent}}%
    \hskip-2\parindent minus 2\parindent%
    \hskip\hsize minus\hsize%
    \kern0pt\parfillskip0pt%
    \oldpar%
    \ifdim\prevdepth=273sp%
        \nobreak%
        \vskip-2\baselineskip%
        \hbox{\strut}%
    \fi%
\fi}

\AtBeginDocument{\def\par{\newpar}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{center}
\textbf{Bla bla}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: latex defines `\par` _all over the place_ in display environments like `center` in lists, in parboxes, in tables...  a definition like that is only usable in a very restricted enviornment where you control the text it isn't usable as a global definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\end{center}` (like almost all latex display and list environments) ends up executing `\endtrivlist` which in turn executes `\@doendpe` defined as

```
\def\@doendpe{\@endpetrue
     \def\par{\@restorepar
              \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
              \everypar{}\par\@endpefalse}\everypar
               {{\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
                \everypar{}\@endpefalse}}
```

This redefines `\par` to control the indentation after the environment. If the `center` is preceded by a paragraph end then the text after it starts a new paragraph.

Section headings use a similar definition of `\par` to suppress the indentation of the first paragraph after a section.

`\par` is redefined in several other places, notably in tables and `minipage`  so basically a definition such as the one suggested in the question can not be used as a global definition (without more invasive changes in latex) but can be used in a restricted environment that is just consisting of simple paragraphs.